# Building a 'table of contents'

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

Consider the following 'sample.xml'

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<level>
    <name>testA</name>
    <level>
        <name>testB</name>  
    </level>
    <level>
        <name>testC</name>  
        <level>
            <name>testD</name>  
            <level>
                <name>testE</name>  
            </level>
        </level>
    </level>
</level>
</root>
```

Using xmlstarlet i can do:

```
xml sel -t -m //level -v name -o " " -v "count(ancestor::*)-1" -o "." -v "count(preceding-sibling::*)" -n sample.xml
```

This produces:

```
testA 0.0
testB 1.1
testC 1.2
testD 2.1
testE 3.1
```

What should i do to get:

```
testA 0.0
testB 1.1
testC 1.2
testD 1.2.1
testE 1.2.1.1
```

In this example i only have 4 levels, but this can be more than 4.

I am thinking of some kind of recursion, are there any links available which can explain how to do that?

Comment: I don't know if this can be done with xpath alone (which is why I took the liberty of adding the xpath tag, so as to alert the heavy xpath artilery to the question. I managed to get your desired output using a somewhat ugly python script using lxml. I can post it, if you are interested. It may also be possible to do something similar with xidel (an xmlstarlet alternative), but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @JackFleeting: part of the beauty of xmlstarlet is that it's easy to change the output, when a slightly different answer is needed.  In the mean time, i have started a C# project to read these XML's, using [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), which is another learning curve 

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using XSLT with the ["tr" command in xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s02.html)...

However your desired output is a little confusing. If "testA" is the first level and you start at zero, why don't all the other entries start at zero? Or maybe "root" is supposed to be zero?

Anyway, here's an example that starts at 1 instead of zero that should get you started...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<root>
    <level>
        <name>testA</name>
        <level>
            <name>testB</name>  
        </level>
        <level>
            <name>testC</name>  
            <level>
                <name>testD</name>  
                <level>
                    <name>testE</name>  
                </level>
            </level>
        </level>
    </level>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="level">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::level">
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">.</xsl:if>
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="level"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command Line**

```
xmlstarlet tr test.xsl input.xml
```

**Output**

```
testA 1
testB 1.1
testC 1.2
testD 1.2.1
testE 1.2.1.1
```

Comment: A should be level 0, and B should be '.1' (or 0.1), but that is indeed wrong in my question..   it is nice from xmlstarlet to create xsl files, using -C, but it lacks the possibility to create a `xmlstartel sel -t ...` line from an xsl. And xsl files are hard to read. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved without recursion, by iterating over
elements on the `ancestor-or-self` [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#axes).

The following `xmlstarlet` command processes all `level` elements using
the inner `-m` (`xsl:for-each`) to handle each path from root to target
(as suggested in comments the shell variable `base` defaults to `0` but
can be set to `1`).

```sh
xmlstarlet select -T -t \
  -m '//level' \
    -v 'concat(name," ")' \
    -m 'ancestor-or-self::level' \
      --if 'position() = 1' \
        -v "'${base:-0}'" \
      --else \
        -o '.' \
        -v 'count(preceding-sibling::level) + 1' \
      -b \
    -b \
    -n \
file.xml
```

Output:

```
testA 0
testB 0.1
testC 0.2
testD 0.2.1
testE 0.2.1.1
```

For a more compact inner `-m` -- producing the same output -- instead

```sh
    -m 'ancestor-or-self::level' \
      --if 'position() != 1' -o '.' -b \
      -v 'count(preceding-sibling::level) + number(position() != 1)' \
    -b \
```

where the count is incremented by 1 for all except the root `level`
where `position()` is `1`.

---

As a variation on the same theme: select elements with the shell
variable `target` and print their paths as XPath expressions using the
XSLT [`current()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-current) function to reference the
element being processed by the inner `-m`:

```sh
target='//level[name="testB" or name="testE"]'
xmlstarlet select -T -t \
  -m "${target}" \
    -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' \
      --var pos='1 + count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])' \
      -v 'concat("/",name(),"[",$pos,"]")' \
    -b \
    -n \
file.xml
```

Output:

```
/root[1]/level[1]/level[1]
/root[1]/level[1]/level[2]/level[1]/level[1]
```